# cant set attribute of type object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

I am getting the response value from apex controller but it is not setting in my attribute beerList. what could be wrong?
controller

```java
public class BeerSearchAuraService {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<sobject> searchBeer(String searchParam){
        String likePAram='%'+searchParam+'%';
        string query='select id, name from Beer__c where name like :likePAram Limit 10';
        List<sobject> sobjectList=Database.query(query);
        return sobjectList;
    }
}
```

Js controller

```js
({
    handleCompEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var searchParam= event.getParam('searchText');
        var action=component.get('c.searchBeer');
        action.setParams({
            searchParam : searchParam
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state= response.getState();
            if(state==='SUCCESS')
            {
                var responseValue=response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('response value is' ,responseValue);
                component.set('v.beerList',responseValue);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

component

```html
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" access="global" controller="BeerSearchAuraService" >
    <aura:handler name="BeerEvent" event="c:SearchEvent" action="{!c.handleCompEvent}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="beerList" type="Object"/>
    <div>
    <c:HeaderComponent TagLine="Beer explorer" Message="Search your beer in an easy way" />
        </div>
    <div>
        <c:BeerSearch />
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.beerList}" var="item">
        {!item.id} ---{!item.name}
        </aura:iteration>
        <c:BeerListComponent recordList="{!v.beerList}"/>
        
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Change this `<aura:attribute name="beerList" type="Object"/>` to `<aura:attribute name="beerList" type="List"/>`

Comment: Tried. doesnt seem to work. :( @NagendraSingh

Comment: Posted as an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have declared, `beerList` in Aura as `Object`.

If you are passing List from backend then declare that as `List`

So changing

```
<aura:attribute name="beerList" type="Object"/>
```

to

```
<aura:attribute name="beerList" type="List"/>
```

Also change your return type to `List<Beer__c>` in Apex code. That should work.

Comment: I have tried changing it to List. But it still didnt work.

Comment: Can you share apex code for `searchBeer`?

Comment: I have shared in the post itself. 1st snippet 
public class BeerSearchAuraService 
Have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your server is returning a list, and your client seems to be expecting an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this as System Admin? A possible reason the user has not read permission of Beer__c object, in Apex you are execution as system context (you have omitted with/out sharing, so by default its without sharing).

To test if the problem is about permissions try this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Object searchBeer(String searchParam){
    String likePAram='%'+searchParam+'%';
    string query='select id, name from Beer__c where name like :likePAram Limit 10';
    List<sobject> sobjectList=Database.query(query);
    return JSON.serialize(sobjectList);
}
```

and check return value.

If previously this you can see correctly.. -> console.log('response value is' ,responseValue); forget my changes :) and try to change Object -> Map